# How to disable autocomplete closing parenthesis in android EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, parentheses

I have a button that when pressed, should insert a left parenthesis `(` in an `EditText` view. The problem is that when this button is pressed, it inserts the left parenthesis and automatically adds a right parenthesis. Any ideas..... thank you in advance. Here is my code

```
public void onClick(View v){
    editText.getText().insert(position,"(");
}
```

The result is () .However the desired output should be (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> Uncheck Insert pair bracket`

Comment: Thank you for help. It seems you misunderstood me. The problem is in the EditText view of the program I am developing, but not in the android studio editor

Comment: There is now a level `General` between `Settings` and `Editor`:
`File -> Settings -> General -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> Uncheck Insert pair brackets (), [], {}, <>`